# EF Core 7 - Fluent API - Many-To-Many - .Map No Overload Takes 1 Argument

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Issue>()
            .HasMany<Person>(issue => issue.Persons)
            .WithMany(person => person.Issues)
            .Map(personIssue =>
            {
                 personIssue.MapLeftKey("IssueId");
                 personIssue.MapRightKey("PersonId");
                 personIssue.ToTable("IssuePerson");
            });
}

public class Issue
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int IssueId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string ExternalIdentifier { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string SummaryShort { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string SummaryLong { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string ProblemStatement { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public DateTime WorkAround { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime Severity { get; set; }

    public DateTime Priority { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public DateTime DateFound { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateReported { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateResolved { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
        = new List<Person>();

    public ICollection<Team> Teams { get; set; }
        = new List<Team>();

    public Person ReportedByPerson { get; set; }

    public Team ReportedByTeam { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string MiddleName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string LastName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public ICollection<PersonRole> PersonRole { get; set; }
        = new List<PersonRole>();

    public ICollection<Location> Locations { get; set; }
        = new List<Location>();

    public ICollection<Issue> Issues { get; set; }
        = new List<Issue>();
}
```

In this code, the `.Map` method is flagged with an error

> No overload takes 1 argument

I can't seem to find the definition of this method via Visual Studio or Google. Has this changed in EF Core 7?

Code example above came from here: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Added the models involved, but please note these tables are involved in other relationships as well.

Comment: It is not Core. It is EF 6 [Map](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.entitytypeconfiguration-1.map?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) method.

Comment: can we see your models?

Comment: Updated question to include the models involved per your request.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov If you post this as an answer then I'll accept it. Thanks.

Comment: I'd really rather not leave this question hanging.  @AlexanderPetrov would you mind posting that as an answer so I can accept it?  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not EF Core. It is EF 6 [Map](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.entitytypeconfiguration-1.map?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) method.